# Beats Studio 3 Wireless via bluetooth on Ubuntu 18.04 does not pair

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

Please help, I use Ubuntu 18.04 on Asus Zenbook UX410U. When trying to connect my earphones Apple Beats Studio 3 Wireless via bluetooth, the built-in bluetooth manager in the settings see them, but is unable to set up or pair. Tried to use Blueman with the same result. While googling found an issue with A2DP, but as far as I understood, it may help, if only the laptop can connect to the earphones, so not my case. Is there any solution to connect Beats to Ubuntu? Thanks in advance!